# Videos in Messages chats look terrible on iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: iphone, messages, video, ichat

I seem to be having an issue with my iPhone 11 Pro. Videos sent from my Mac to iMessage chats look like garbage (tiny, really low-rezzed down, pixellated when viewed) on my phone. Videos sent from my phone look like garbage on my Mac in the same chat thread. Videos sent from other people’s phones look like garbage on my phone, but fine on the Mac in the same chat, and fine on other people’s phones (no iPhone 11s though) in the same chat.

It’s definitely not a storage issue - I have several hundred GB free. The low-res image setting in Messages is off.

Update: I have isolated this to only happening in group chats. Regular 1:1 message threads seem to have fine videos.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Send As SMS, Text Message Forwarding, or Low Quality Image Mode enabled under settings? Low Quality Image Mode is most likely culprit. Go to settings->messages->Low Quality Image Mode (Scroll all the way down)

Comment: I have send as sms and text message forwarding both turned on, but so do the other participants in the chat, and the issue happens with both sent and received images.

As I said in the original post, I have low quality image mode turned off.